# Using \textipa{x} inside tikzcd (maths) environment

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd, tipa

I'd like to use [`tipa`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) IPA characters inside a [`tikzcd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) environment. The code compiles but the characters don't render correctly. Strangely, there is no related warning.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\section{Tikz-cd environments, tipa broken}

\begin{tikzcd}
    O \arrow[r, tail, two heads, dashed] & \textipa{O}
\end{tikzcd}


\section{Actual tipa symbol}

\textipa{O}

\begin{IPA}
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```

[image: tikzcd and tipa inside]

I gather that this issue could be due to `tikz-cd` using math mode and I was wondering if anyone knew how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `amsmath` and putting it in a `\text{}` macro seems to help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
   \usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\section{Tikz-cd environments, tipa broken}

\begin{tikzcd}
    O \arrow[r, tail, two heads, dashed] & \text{\textipa{O}}
\end{tikzcd}


\section{Actual tipa symbol}

\textipa{O}

\begin{IPA}
    OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
\end{IPA}

\end{document}
```